# TPL DataFlow call a dataflow twice times

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I designed a complex dataflow consisting of various DataBlocks. I send a packet into the flow and receive a result on the end.

I work with

```
input.Post();
input.Complete();

// and later with
ReceiveAsync();
```

For the first call all works fine, but I don't know how to send the second data-packet through into the flow graph.

Inside the graph I also must use a `WriteOnceBlock`, can this be a problem for call the flow twice times?

Comment: You should post your flow for examination we can't tell you why it doesn't work without seeing it. In general though, if you've called `Complete` on your flow you won't be able to send any further data through. Also, as its name implies a `WriteOnceBlock` can only be written to once, but that really shouldn't be in your main pipeline, likely it appears on a branch but again only one piece of data will be written to it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use any of [`TPL Dataflow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) blocks after you've called the [`Complete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.idataflowblock.complete.aspx) method for them or for those who linked to them with completion propagation. So either you need to recreate your pipeline for each of your call, or (which is preferred) not to call [`Complete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.idataflowblock.complete.aspx) just for a one call.

Suggestions to your design:

- It seems that your're getting the data with `Post/Receive` methods in your pipeline, which can be substitute by [linking the blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228604.aspx#Forming%20the%20Pipeline). Moreover, you can use the [completion propagation for this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions.propagatecompletion.aspx), so you'll remove all the continuation handlers in your code, if any.
- Are you sure that you needs the [`WriteOnceBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194820.aspx)? You can switch it to [`Broadcast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160447.aspx), so you still has a value for a data, but it can be overridden by next call.
- If this is still not an option, you can unlink your [`WriteOnceBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194820.aspx) either by specifying the [`MaxMessages` for linked blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228600.aspx) or by storing the `IDisposable` result of the [`LinkTo` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.linkto.aspx) so you can remove it for your next call, and create a new one [`WriteOnceBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194820.aspx).